# XCode7 how to connect window referencing outlet to files' owner in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xcode7.3

I want to be able to connect the window referencing outlet to the File's owner as I did in my previous XCode project (before version 7!).

[image: oldproject]

But now in XCode Version 7 if I control drag from File's Owner to the register window it doesn't create the outlet anymore, I can't remember exactly how I did it previously but I am certain that something has changed.

[image: new project]

Comment: I managed to manually edit the .xib file and add the references!